# Azure AD B2C Custom UI with SAML relying party

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to use a SAML relying party and send a custom UI content definition parameter, as disccribed in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Example:

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ContentDefinitionParameters>
        <Parameter Name="campaignId">{OAUTH-KV:campaignId}</Parameter>
    </ContentDefinitionParameters>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    ...
</RelyingParty>
```

`OAUTH-KV` doesnt work with SAML (obvisously).

Is there any other way of getting a parameter sent with SAML that I can use as a ContentDefinitionParameter?

FYI we are already using `{SAML:ProviderName}`, `{SAML:Issuer}` and `{SAML:Subject}` for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported values will the the claim resolvers listed in the documentation for SAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#saml

The best candidate for passing arbitrary data in the query string is `{SAML:RelayState}`.

The main reason for the difference is that OAuth explicitly allows for arbitrary parameters in the request whereas SAML is much more strict.